# DOA pattern without dependency injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, dependency-injection, dao, factory-pattern

In our company we use DAO pattern in almost every project. This has some pros and cons but the question is not about that. We just started another project but in comparison with the others it is very simple and is not based on a DI framework. Just a simple servlet run on a cloud.

My question is: How to implement DAO pattern when DI is not available. How to mock DAOs later? They have to initialized somewhere probably inside a service class. Is it a good practice to use reflection during the tests and replace real DAOs with mocks? Another view is to use factoryDAO .. but how to use factory to return mock objects?

Comment: If you know dependency injection is useful, why don't you use a DI framework?

Comment: The application is run on a cloud. DI frameworks are not suitable for that. I need to have a fast cold start to make the application prepared for unpredictable traffic spikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply inject the DAO "by hand":

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private MyService service = new MyService(new MyDao());

    ...
}
```

And in your test:

```
public class MyServiceTest {

    private MyDao mockDao;
    private MyService service;

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        mockDao = mock(MyDao.class);
        service = new MyService(mockDao);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: What if I need more than one DAO per service ? 
    class MyService(MyDao myDAO, OtherDAO otherDAO, FunnyDAO funnyDAO ); Does not look like a good design.

Comment: How would that be different with a DI framework? If your service needs 3 DAOs to work, isn't it normal to pass them as arguments to the service constructor? You can use setters if you want, but that's worse.

Comment: Is not better to use DAOFactory instead of all of these DAOs in a Service constructor ? Thanks to this services could use whatever DAO they want without changing them constructors signatures when the specification was changed.

Comment: If you use a factory inside the service to get DAO instances, then you're bnot using dependency injection anymore, unless you inject (and mock) the factory itself. DI is what allows injecting mock dependencies in tests. What's wrong in refactoring services when they need a new DAO? That's actually a good thing: it forces you to fix the test when the service changes.